# Python subprocess script failing

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, rm

Have written the below script to delete files in a folder not matching the dates in the "keep" period. Eg. Delete all except files partly matching this name.

The command works from the shell but fails with the subprocess call.

```
/bin/rm /home/backups/!(*"20170920"*|*"20170919"*|*"20170918"*|*"20170917"*|*"20170916"*|*"20170915"*|*"20170914"*)
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import subprocess

### Editable Variables
keepdays=7
location="/home/backups"

count=0
date_string=''
for count in range(0,keepdays):
    if(date_string!=""):
        date_string+="|"
    keepdate = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=count)).strftime("%Y%m%d")
    date_string+="*\""+keepdate+"\"*"

full_cmd="/bin/rm "+location+"/!("+date_string+")"
subprocess.call([full_cmd], shell=True)
```

This is what the script returns:

```
#./test.py

/bin/rm /home/backups/!(*"20170920"*|*"20170919"*|*"20170918"*|*"20170917"*|*"20170916"*|*"20170915"*|*"20170914"*)
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Python version is Python 2.7.12

Comment: when you are running the command from shell/terminal, you are using bash's expansion of globs, and other substitution. Python, however, is relying on `/bin/sh` (and not `/bin/bash`) to run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @hjpotter said, subprocess will use `/bin/sh` as default shell, which doesn't support the kind of globbing you want to do. See [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html). You can change that using the `executable` parameter to `subprocess.call()` with a more appropriate shell (`/bin/bash` or `/bin/zsh` for example): `subprocess.call([full_cmd], executable="/bin/bash", shell=True)`

BUT you can be a lot better served by Python itself, you don't need to call a subprocess to delete a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import re
import os
import os.path

### Editable Variables
keepdays=7
location="/home/backups"

now = datetime.now()
keeppatterns = set((now - timedelta(days=count)).strftime("%Y%m%d") for count in range(0, keepdays))

for filename in os.listdir(location):
    dates = set(re.findall(r"\d{8}", filename))
    if not dates or dates.isdisjoint(keeppatterns):
        abs_path = os.path.join(location, filename)
        print("I am about to remove", abs_path)
        # uncomment the line below when you are sure it won't delete any valuable file
        #os.path.delete(abs_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I tried the executable arg in the subprocess which still threw an error, but your replacement script worked perfectly!